# How do I know it's time to start using SQL Caching on my website?

Tags: sql, caching

I'm running a fairly new website that heavily consists user generated content.  I have read about SQL caching and I'm just wondering when you know it's time to switch over to SQL caching.  The site doesn't appear to be slow or anything but It would be great to hear what sorts of signs start appearing to warn me when I should start looking into implementing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Profile your application - if you are experiencing performance bottlenecks accessing your database then introduce a caching layer to alleviate the pressure.

Otherwise (if you don't have any performance bottlenecks) I wouldn't do anything until a problem arises.